# checkbox array length getting as zero

Tags: php, html, checkbox

when  i am executing the below code, i am getting check box array length as zero.

```
<?PHP

if(isset($_POST['Submit3']))
{

$check = $_POST['checkList'];
echo count($check);

for($i=0;$i<count($check);$i++)
{

 $id = $_POST['id'][$i];
 $year = $_POST['year'][$i];
 $month = $_POST['month'][$i];
 $leaves = $_POST['leaves'][$i];
 $working = $_POST['working'][$i];
 $payment_days = $_POST['payment'][$i];
 $bonus = $_POST['bonus'][$i];
 $ctc = $_POST['ctc'][$i];
 $basic = $_POST['basic'][$i];
 $hra = $_POST['hra'][$i];
 $sa = $_POST['sa'][$i];
 $ma = $_POST['ma'][$i];
 $con = $_POST['con'][$i];
 $ta = $_POST['ta'][$i];
 $pf = $_POST['pf'][$i];
 $pt = $_POST['pt'][$i];
 $vpf = $_POST['vpf'][$i];
 $net_pay = $_POST['netpay'][$i];

 $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO salaries(employee_id,ctc,basic_pay,hra,special_allowances,medical_allowances,travell_allowances,conveyance,provident_fund,professional_tax,vpf,bonus,working_days,leaves,payment_days,net_pay,month,year)VALUES('$id','$ctc','$basic','$hra','$sa','$ma','$ta','$con','$pf','$pt','$vpf','$bonus','$working','$leaves','$payment_days','$net_pay','$month','$year')") or die(mysql_error());

 if($result)
 {
    $scount++;
    header("Location:?pid=employee_management/view-emp&minsert=success");
 }
 else
 {
    header("Location:?pid=employee_management/run-payroll&insert=fail");
 }


 }
 }

 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').dataTable( {
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
            } );
        } );
    </script>
 <script type="application/javascript">
 function delrow() {
 var ok=confirm("Are you sure want to delete");
 if(ok)
   return true;
 else
   return false;
 }
 </script>     
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function validate()
 {
    if(document.frmreg.year.value == "")
    {
      alert("Please Select Year.\n")
      document.frmreg.year.focus();
      return false;
    }
    if(document.frmreg.month.value == "")
    {
      alert("Please Select Month.\n")
      document.frmreg.month.focus();
      return false;
    }


  }
  function no_of_days(mo,ye)
  { 

        var m=parseInt(mo);
        var y=parseInt(ye);
        var days="";

        if((m==1) || (m==3) || (m==5) || (m==7) || (m==8) || (m==10) || (m==12))
        {
          days = 31;

        }
        else if((m==4) || (m==6) || (m==9) || (m==11))
        { 
          days = 30; 
        }
        else if(m==2)
        {
          if(((y%4==0)&&(y%100!=0))||(y%400==0))
          {
                 days = 29;
          }
          else
          {
                  days = 28;
          }
        }

      document.frmreg.no_days.value = days;

}
</script>

<link href="../../css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../css/demo_table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body onLoad="document.frmreg.search2.focus()">
<?PHP
 if ($_GET['insert']=="fail")
 {
     $strr= "Salaries  not Inserted";
 }
 ?>

 <table width="830" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3">
  <tr>
    <td height="30" class="heading5">Run Payroll</td>
    <td height="30" colspan="9" class="txnormalbold"><?PHP echo $strr; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <form name="frmreg" id="frmreg" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return validate()">
   <tr>

    <td height="60" width="236" align="center" class="txnormalbold"> Year  &nbsp;:&nbsp; 
    <select name="year" id="year" class="formfield" style="width:120px;" onchange="return no_of_days(document.frmreg.month.value,this.value)">
        <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
       <?php
        for ($x=2010; $x<=2050; $x++)
          {
            echo'<option value="'.$x.'">'.$x.'</option>'; 
          } 
        ?> 
      </select><span style="color:#000099">*</span></td>
    <td width="200" align="left" class="txnormalbold"> Month  &nbsp;:&nbsp;
       <select name="month" id="month" class="formfield" style="width:120px;" onchange="return no_of_days(this.value,document.frmreg.year.value)">
          <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
          <option value="01">January</option>
          <option value="02">February</option>
          <option value="03">March</option>
          <option value="04">April</option>
          <option value="05">May</option>
          <option value="06">June</option>
          <option value="07">July</option>
          <option value="08">August</option>
          <option value="09">September</option>
          <option value="10">October</option>
          <option value="11">November</option>
          <option value="12">December</option>
      </select><span style="color:#000099">*</span></td>
      <td width="161" align="left" class="txnormalbold">Working days  &nbsp;:&nbsp;
      <input type="text" name="no_days" id="no_days" class="formfield" style="width:50px;" /></td>
   <td width="72" align="left"><input type="submit" name="dsubmit" id="dsubmit" value="Submit" class="testfield_button" /></td>
    <td width="71"></td>
    <td width="40"></td>
    <td width="11"></td>
    <td width="2"></td>
    <td width="2"></td>
    <td width="2"></td>
   </tr>
</form>
<?PHP
  if(isset($_POST['dsubmit']))
  {
    $n_d = $_POST['no_days'];
    $mnth = $_POST['month'];
    $m_r = mysql_query("SELECT * from months where id='$mnth'");
    $m_arr = mysql_fetch_array($m_r);
    $month1 = $m_arr['name'];
    $yr = $_POST['year'];
?>
<form name="fmreg" id="fmreg" method="post" action="">
  <tr>

    <td height="40" class="txnormalboldred" colspan="2" align="right" >Payroll for the Month of <?PHP echo ucfirst($month1); ?>/<?PHP echo $yr; ?></td>
     <td width="72" align="right"><input type="button" name="checkall2" id="checkall2" value="Check All"   onclick="javascript:markAll()"  class="careermanage" /></td>
    <td width="71" align="left"><input type="button" name="checkall22" id="checkall22" value="Uncheck"   onclick="javascript:unMarkAll()"  class="careermanage" /></td>
    <td class="txnormalboldred" colspan="6" align="center" >&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="10" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px">        <table width="830" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="display" id="example" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="middle" class="txnormalbold"><table width="830" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="display" id="example2" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="3%" ></th>
          <th width="5%" align="center">Emp. Id</th>
          <th width="7%" align="center">Name</th>
          <th width="5%" align="center">Basic</th>
          <th width="5%" align="center">HRA</th>
          <th width="5%" align="center">Spl. All.</th>
          <th width="5%" align="center">Med. All.</th>
          <th width="5%" align="center">Tra. All.</th>
          <th width="5%" align="center">Conv.</th>
          <th width="5%" align="center">Pro. Fund</th>
          <th width="5%" align="center">Prof. Tax</th>
          <th width="5%" align="center">Net Inc.</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th width="3%" ></th>
          <th width="5%" align="center">Emp. Id</th>
          <th width="7%" align="center">Name</th>
          <th width="5%" align="center">Basic</th>
          <th width="5%" align="center">HRA</th>
          <th width="5%" align="center">Spl. All.</th>
          <th width="5%" align="center">Med. All.</th>
          <th width="5%" align="center">Tra. All.</th>
          <th width="5%" align="center">Conv.</th>
          <th width="5%" align="center">Pro. Fund</th>
          <th width="5%" align="center">Prof. Tax</th>
          <th width="5%" align="center">Net Inc.</th>

        </tr>
      </tfoot>
      <tbody>
    <?php 
    $sel=mysql_query("select * from employees");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($sel);
  while($res=mysql_fetch_array($sel))
  {
      $eid = $res['employee_id'];
      $ename = $res['employee_first_name'];
      $ctc = $res['mctc'];
      $basic = $res['mbasic_pay'];
      $hra = $res['mhra'];
      $sa = $res['mspecial_allowances'];
      $ma = $res['mmedical_allowances'];
      $ta = $res['mtravell_allowances'];
      $con = $res['mconveyance'];
      $pf = $res['mprovident_fund'];
      $pt = $res['mprofessional_tax'];

      $one_day_base = $basic/30;
      $tot_basic = ($n_d*$one_day_base);

      $tot_ear = $tot_basic + $hra + $sa + $ma + $ta + $con; 
      $tot_ded = $pf + $pt;
      $net_pay = round($tot_ear - $tot_ded);

     ?>

        <tr>
          <td height="24"  align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="checkList[]" id="checkList[]" value="<?php echo $eid;?>"/></td>
          <td height="24" align="center"><?php echo $eid;?></td>
          <td height="24" align="center"><?php echo $ename;?></td>
          <td height="24" align="center" ><?php echo $basic;?></td>
          <td height="24" align="center" ><?php echo $hra;?></td>
          <td height="24" align="center"><?php echo $sa;?></td>
          <td height="24" align="center"><?php echo $ma;?> </td>
          <td height="24" align="center"><?php echo $ta;?></td>
          <td height="24" align="center"><?php echo $con;?></td>
          <td height="24" align="center"><?php echo $pf;?></td>
          <td height="24" align="center"><?php echo $pt;?></td>
          <td height="24" align="center"><?PHP echo number_format(round($net_pay),2);?>         </td> 


    </tr>


  <input type="hidden" name="id[]" id="id" value="<?PHP echo $eid; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="year[]" id="year" value="<?PHP echo $yr; ?>" />     
  <input type="hidden" name="month[]" id="month" value="<?PHP echo $mnth; ?>" />    
  <input type="hidden" name="leaves[]" id="leaves" value="0" />
  <input type="hidden" name="working[]" id="working" value="<?PHP echo $n_d; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="payment[]" id="payment" value="<?PHP echo $n_d; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden"  name="bonus[]" id="bonus" value="0"/>
  <input type="hidden"  name="ctc[]" id="ctc" value="<?PHP echo $ctc; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden"  name="basic[]" id="basic"  value="<?PHP echo $basic; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden"  name="hra[]" id="hra"  value="<?PHP echo $hra; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden"  name="sa[]" id="sa" value="<?PHP echo $sa; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden"  name="ma[]" id="ma" value="<?PHP echo $ma; ?>" />     
  <input type="hidden"  name="con[]" id="con" value="<?PHP echo $con; ?>"/>
  <input type="hidden"  name="ta[]" id="ta" value="<?PHP echo $ta; ?>"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="pf[]" id="pf"  value="<?PHP echo $pf; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden"  name="pt[]" id="pt" value="<?PHP echo $pt; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden"  name="vpf[]" id="vpf" value="<?PHP $res['vpf']; ?>" />      
  <input type="hidden"  name="netpay[]" id="netpay" value="<?PHP $net_pay; ?>"/>



        <?php 

         } // end of while

        ?>
      </tbody>
    </table></td></tr>
  </thead>

    </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td colspan="4" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit3" id="Submit3" value="Run Payroll" class="testfield_button" /></td>
 <td colspan="6"></td>
  </tr>
   </form>
    <?php 
     }
    ?> 
  </table>


</body>
</html>
```

how to get the array length?, is it correct?, if any mistakes present in the above code please correct it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please sanitize your input. Your code is wide open for sql injection.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Thank you for your suggestion.its just an academic project nothing to do with that.

Comment: try var_dump($check) near your echo statement.let us know the output.

Comment: @Vivek. Thanks. But its printing as Null.

Comment: @tinturintu use firebug or page source , check if these $eid are printing for each row or not ?

Comment: @Vivek yeah its printing.

Comment: @tinturintu At line no. 62, Replace  <script type="application/javascript"> with  <script type="script/javascript">.

Comment: @Vivek even i am getting as null.

Comment: @tinturintu I have tried your code , its working fine for me. Kindly Turn on your php errors(php.ini) and look for the problem .

Comment: @Vivek How to turn on errors in php.ini file,can you please guide me.

Comment: @Vivek i am not getting errors, only notices. Please help me, i am new to php.